# "Fine, fine that" - meaning in a snippet (a story)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

Reading a story by A. Blackwood:

> “Singular,yes, these last words of dying men,” the tall man was
> saying, “very singular. You remember Newman’s: ‘More light,’ wasn’t
> it?” The bookseller nodded. “**Fine**,” he said, “**fine, that!**”
> There was a pause. Mr, Jenkyn stooped lower over the pens. “**This,
> too, was fine in its way,**” the gentleman added, straightening up to
> go; “the old promise, you see, unfulfilled but not forgotten.

They are talking about the last words of their friend. I do not understand what "fine" means in this context.
Also this reference to the Newman's: More Light. What does it mean? I assume they refer to words of another dying man, whose last words were "More light", probably?

Comment: It's actually Goethe whose last words were supposedly "Mehr licht" (more light). https://www.phrases.org.uk/famous-last-words/goethe.html Does this refer to Cardinal Newman or to a character in the story?

Comment: ***Fine, that = Those are fine words*** (to be remembered as one's final dying words, but ironically the speaker here seems to have ***misremembered*** who actually said "More light!" on their deathbed).

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, I was not aware of the possible reference to Goethe. As for your question, there is no Newman in the story, so I guess it refers to the cardinal?

Comment: Presumably, as @FumbleFingers implies, the 'tall man' attributed Goethe's words to Cardinal Newman. (I had to look up who said it - I only knew it was a German.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rewrite it like this:

> "Do you remember Newman's last words?  They were 'More light.'"
> "Yes, that was a very fine thing to say."

The [meaning of **fine**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine) is its normal one,

> superior in kind, quality, or appearance : EXCELLENT

Comment: "Fine, that!" is an expression used in British English but not so much American.